# Seaborn FacetGrid - Changing y-axis rotation for all plots?

Tags: python, seaborn, facet

I have used a FacetGRid, and managed to change the rotation of the x-axis for one column, but not the other. Also is there anyway to get the labels on the x-axis for all the separate plots?

I have tried

```
grid.set_xticklabels(rotation=65, horizontalalignment='right')
```

Which completely erases the labels, and

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Which works fine on the right hand column, but the left column stays the same (see image)

my code is:

`grid = sns.catplot(x='Nationality', y='count', 
                   row='Age', col='Gender', 
                   hue='Type',
                   data=dfNorthumbria2, kind='bar', ci=None)`

[image: this is what it looks like.]

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer for the rotation -

```
for axes in grid.axes.flat:
axes.set_xticklabels(axes.get_xticklabels(), rotation=65, horizontalalignment='right')
```

[This excellent blog](https://www.drawingfromdata.com/how-to-rotate-axis-labels-in-seaborn-and-matplotlib) managed to explain it all with relation to using FacetGrid and the columns/rows.